# RDLC Report is only showing first item in the list

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm trying to modify an existing rdlc file in a C# Windows Forms project  The report works, but it only shows the first item in the List.  How do I get it to show 1 page for each item in the List?

My report's dataset is a list with these values:

[image]

When I view the report in the report viewer, I only see the 1st item in the list on one page instead of two pages with 1 item on each page.

[image]

Here is the code for my class:

```
public class WorkOrderItemViewModel
{
    public string FilterSize { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
}
```

Here's where I call the report in the report viewer:

```
private Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer OrderSummaryReportViewer;
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("WorkOrderItemsDataSet", workOrderDetailViewModel.WorkOrderItems));
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
reportDataSource1.Name = "WorkOrderItemsDataSet";
reportDataSource1.Value = null;
reportDataSource2.Name = "WorkOrderDetailDataSet";
reportDataSource2.Value = null;
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Pick List";
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "NTSupply.CustomFilter.Reports.OrderSummaryReport.rdlc";
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.Name = "OrderSummaryReportViewer";
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(960, 621);
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.TabIndex = 0;
this.OrderSummaryReportViewer.RenderingComplete += new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RenderingCompleteEventHandler(this.OrderSummaryReportViewer_RenderingComplete);
OrderSummaryReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Here's the rdlc in the designer:
[image]

Here's the code for the rdlc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="Textbox21">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>Finished Good:</Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                  <TextDecoration>None</TextDecoration>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style>
              <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
            </Style>
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox11</rd:DefaultName>
        <Top>0.17187in</Top>
        <Left>0.05in</Left>
        <Height>0.25in</Height>
        <Width>1.33333in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <VerticalAlign>Bottom</VerticalAlign>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
      <Textbox Name="FilterSize1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>=Fields!FilterSize.Value</Value>
                <Style />
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style>
              <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
            </Style>
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>FilterSize1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Top>0.17187in</Top>
        <Left>1.45278in</Left>
        <Height>0.25in</Height>
        <Width>1.55208in</Width>
        <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <VerticalAlign>Bottom</VerticalAlign>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>0.625in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>8in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeader>
      <Height>0.5625in</Height>
      <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
      <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
      <ReportItems>
        <Textbox Name="OrderID">
          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
          <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                  <Value>=Fields!OrderID.Value</Value>
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                  </Style>
                </TextRun>
              </TextRuns>
              <Style>
                <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
              </Style>
            </Paragraph>
          </Paragraphs>
          <rd:DefaultName>OrderID</rd:DefaultName>
          <Top>0.125in</Top>
          <Left>0.09861in</Left>
          <Height>0.25in</Height>
          <Width>2.90625in</Width>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>Solid</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
        </Textbox>
      </ReportItems>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </PageHeader>
    <LeftMargin>0.25in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>0.25in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>0.25in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>0.25in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="NTSupplyCustomFilterViewModels">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>af4b9e33-ffdc-42b0-82b7-cd63dceba934</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="WorkOrderItemsDataSet">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>NTSupplyCustomFilterViewModels</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
      </Query>
        <Field Name="FilterSize">
          <DataField>FilterSize</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="OrderID">
          <DataField>OrderID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName>NTSupply.CustomFilter.ViewModels</rd:DataSetName>
        <rd:TableName>WorkOrderItemViewModel</rd:TableName>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType>NTSupply.CustomFilter.ViewModels.WorkOrderItemViewModel, CustomFilterApplication, Version=1.0.1.57, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</rd:ObjectDataSourceType>
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>a8be0d7c-0875-4915-91df-572c8fded42f</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Edit:

Suggestion was for adding a table.  This works in as far as adding a table and the page break displays the table data on multiple pages, but it's not quite what I need.  Unfortunately, the request isn't for a table of data, but a formatted document with different labels.  For instance, adding a table puts the second row of table data on the next page, but the label and values outside the table are only on the first page.  I need those elements on a new page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Report with Grouping and Page Break Settings]

It does not look like your report has enough parts to it.  If you want one record per page, you really need to have a table added to your report.  From there, add a "Group" such as group by product, customer, company, whatever.  Once you have the group, you can add your columns to show the data you want respectively.  Finally, if you right-click / properties on the group you can see where you can set the page breaks.  From the report you have listed, I don't see any such indicators of these elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response; I really appreciate it.  The table worked in putting data in the table on a second page, but I need elements outside of a strict table structure.  See my updated question.  Basically I don't want just a list of values, but I need a specifically formatted report.  In my example, the label "Finished Good" and the value for that item would appear on page 1 and page 2.

Comment: @boilers222, can you edit your original post.  Please add like 5-6 rows of data you want to present.  It could be just how you prepare the table.  You can add multiple rows within the group header which could be your primary part, then the detail band shows your details.  I am not exactly getting the context of your page/break spread.